# open a file saved in internal storage using implicit intent app chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

**What I am trying to achieve:**
show app chooser to allow user to choose the app they want to use for viewing.
Click on recyclerview item to show app chooser.
given the app user pick, start the app and show the file.

user click on this recyclerview item

[image]

App will show app chooser to the user. Given selected app, user will be redirected to the selected app to view the  file.

[image]

**Issues:**

when I select an app, a toast from the app appears notifying something went wrong

[image]

additional details:
the file is stored in internal storage, within the app's files directory

[image]

What I've tried so far:

I've followed the reference provided by google regarding sharing files in internal storage with other app. [ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

my code:

- code to execute the intent.

```
    override fun openFile(attachment: Attachment) {
            val filePath = File(requireContext().filesDir, "attachments/${attachment.type}")
            val newFile = File(filePath, attachment.name)
            val contentUri= try {
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "applicationId.fileprovider", newFile)
            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.e("DetailsFragment", "openFile FileProvider: ${e.message}")
                null
            }
            
            contentUri?.let {
                val extension = fileManager.getExtension(it)
                val mime = fileManager.getMime(extension!!)
                val title = "View in"
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.setDataAndType(it, mime)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                intent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", it)
                val selector = Intent.createChooser(intent, title)
    
                Log.i(
                    "DetailsFragment",
                    "openFile - uri: ${it}, extension: ${extension}, data: ${intent.data}, mime: ${intent.type}"
                )
                try {
                    requireActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, selector)
                    requireActivity().startActivity(selector)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("DetailsFragment", "openFile - errorMsg: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
```

- Logcat from openFile(). (No exception in logcat)

```
    openFile - uri: content://applicationId.fileprovider/files/attachments/jpg/IMG_20221124_143655.jpg, extension: jpg, data: content://applicationId.fileprovider/files/attachments/jpg/IMG_20221124_143655.jpg, mime: image/jpeg
```

- manifest

```
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    
    </provider>
```

- xml/file_paths

```
    <paths>
        <files-path
            name="files"
            path="." />
    </paths>
```

Comment: try this one     <root-path
        name="root"
        path="." />

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The result is still the same, issue persist

Comment: Check its file provider authority string: `${applicationId}.fileprovider` vs `"applicationId.fileprovider"`. I suspect `${applicationId}` value may not be the `"applicationId"` string

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking. It is the string for the application id. I've tried it by hardcoding the application package name at first. The log returned also showed the application package name

Comment: This is all about ACTION_SEND and you did not even mention it. Instead you talked about 'the app chooser' .

Comment: `redirected to the selected app to view the file.` No. To share the file. To view a file by another app use ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Try without clipdata.

Comment: Try without chooser .

Comment: `What I am trying to achieve: ` is unclear.

Comment: hi @blackapps, Thanks for the help. it works. Will revise my post to make it more readable and understandable. thanks again and appreciate the help.

Comment: @blackapps just realized why I rejected to use ACTION_VIEW and opt for ACTION_SEND. My emulator only has the default app to view the app, that's why app chooser is not shown. Changing the intent to ACTION_SEND shows the app chooser which result to the issue "Error, could not load media" shown above. 
App chooser with ACTION_VIEW works on my phone because there are alternative app for user to view the file. Anyway, thanks again for the help.